# How to pass item data from .net MVC WebGrid to Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working in such a weird scenario, what i want to accomplish is the following:
A column in my Webgrid has a button, when it gets pressed i show a Partial View as a Bootstrap Modal. The problem is that i need to get @item.id from webgrid selected row before showing Partial View, in order to pass that data as a parameter that i will further use to display more data in that Partial View (modal).

(View)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showModal').click(function () {
            var url = $('#caModal').data('url');

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#caContainer').html(data);

                $('#caModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='caModal' class='modal fade' role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("AsignarCotizaciones")'>
            <div id='caContainer'>
            </div>
        </div>

@grid.Table(
                    tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-bordered",
                    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                    columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column(header: "VENDEDOR", format: @<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@SIC.Controllers.CotizacionController.ConvertByteArrayToBase64(@item.id_Emp)" alt="" height="80" width="70" class="img-circle">),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "nombre_Emp", header: "NOMBRE"),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "apaterno_Emp", header: "APELLIDO"),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "nombre_Art", header: "ARTICULO"),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "nombrecli_CotIns", header: "CLIENTE"),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "fecha_CotIns", header: "FECHA"),
                        grid.Column(header: "⇨", format: @<text><button id="showModal" class="btn btn-info">Asignar</button></text>)
```

(Controller)

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AsignarCotizaciones()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

I'm trying to be as explicit as i can, is there anything i could do?

Comment: First you have invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) - use a class name instead. You can add the value as a `data-` attribute and extract it in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `data-id` to your button and add css class for example `name`

```
grid.Column(header: "⇨", format: 
                  @<text><button class="name btn btn-info" 
                  data-id="@item.id_Emp">Asignar</button>
                 </text>)
```

then update controller

```
 public ActionResult AsignarCotizaciones(string id)
    {
       // YOUR LOGIC FOR EXAMPLE
        var model = _repository.FindAll(u => u.Id == id)
        return PartialView(model );
    }
```

finally update your js

```
           $(document).on("click", ".name", function () {
                var id_emp = $(this).data('id');
                var url = $('#caModal').data('url');
                $.get(url, { id: d_emp }, function (data) {
                    $('#caContainer').html(data);
                    $('#caModal').modal('show');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Seems to be working, but how do i catch that parameter (model) inside the Partial View?

Comment: I did a model list from Controller and in the View i declare model list, so now i can use that model data. Thank you!!